# how to create more than one element in the DOM with js using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, dom

Well, the result I want to get is my `div` element should have the same numbers of `p` elements as the **array**.

In order to do this, I tried using a `for loop` but it just **create one** `p` element, so I didn't work.

Anyone have idea how to do this? (I'm just learning js).

```
const diccionario = () => {
    var dama = ["bird:pajaro", "car:carro", "house:csa", "camis"];

    document.getElementById("dic").addEventListener("click", () => {
        var pes = document.createElement("p");
        for(var i = 0;  i < dama.length; i++){
            pes.innerHTML = dama[i];
            document.getElementById("cuadro").appendChild(pes);     
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Move the `var pes` line 1 line down (inside the for loop) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the element *inside* the loop. If you create it outside the loop, then when you call `appendChild`, it will get removed from wherever it was previously in the DOM:

```
const diccionario = () => {
    var dama = ["bird:pajaro", "car:carro", "house:csa", "camis"];

    document.getElementById("dic").addEventListener("click", () => {
        for(var i = 0;  i < dama.length; i++){
            var pes = document.createElement("p"); // <----------------
            pes.innerHTML = dama[i];
            document.getElementById("cuadro").appendChild(pes);     
        }
    })
}
```

`appendChild` doesn't create a copy of the existing element - rather, it *just appends* the existing element.

Comment: If someone create element outside and clone it inside using `cloneNode` rather than using `createElement` will it increase performance?

Comment: I tried it, but I don't see a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Kenny When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)